# Firebase Login button non-responsive. Not creating new users or errors

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

So i am pretty new to React Native and emulating devices on Windows but I'm taking a tutorial online and have followed the code/instruction precisely but for some reason I am not getting any response to **Firebase** or receiving an error message either.
In this section of the tutorial, we are setting up a basic form and using Firebase to log users in and out of our application. We've created re-usable components from the previous app, including the button to Login. Unfortunately I don't think the button is responding or Firebase isn't connecting. I've uploaded my code on Github.com and here is the link to the repository and my code:

https://github.com/michalladon/authorization

Here are the corresponding code snippets as well:

Login Form Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  state = { email: '', password: '', error: '' }

  onButtonPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(() => {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .catch(() => {
          this.setState({ error: 'Authentication Failed.' });
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Input
            placeholder="user@gmail.com"
            label="Email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
          />
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          <Input
            secureTextEntry
            placeholder="password"
            label="Password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
            style={{ height: 20, width: 100 }}
          />
        </CardSection>
        <Text style={styles.errorTextStyle}>
          {this.state.error}
        </Text>
        <CardSection>
          <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
            Login
          </Button>
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  errorTextStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: 'red'
  }
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Reusable Button Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {
  const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = {
  textStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#007aff',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10
  },
  buttonStyle: {
      flex: 1,
      alignSelf: 'stretch',
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      borderRadius: 5,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#007aff',
      marginLeft: 5,
      marginRight: 5
  }
};

export { Button };
```

Does anyone know what my issue is? I've looked up questions in my class and tried somethings but nothings changed. Firebase has no record of new users and my app ran on a Nexus 5 emulator through Android Studio on Windows shows no errors either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The components should be under the src/components folder. The Button and the Loginform are the two files causing issues

Comment: This question isn't going to be very useful for the community, with no code in it. If you can post the minimal code needed to reproduce the issue, people will be able to help you better, and future readers will be able to learn from your question.

Comment: Sorry Im still kind of new to all of this but I figured the git repo would be more respected. Ill add the code snippets in now

Comment: Try looking into logcat in Android Studio to see if there are any warnings or errors https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: @HonzaKalfus so I have an updated version of Android Studio. and importing my project is beyond my understanding....so Ive been running the emulator via the command line. But even after trying your fixes...it did not work. So i tested it with my actual phone....When i replaced `.catch with .then`it gave me an error of invalid user
then it started giving me a bad email format error which i tried to fix  by adding .trim() to each email in the auth methods but still no use. So I changed the codes back to `.catch` ran it on my phone it worked perfectly. Confused as to why not in the emulator thou

Comment: @Michal Yeah sorry, your original code was ok, it was just confusing, that's why I deleted my answer. It's possible that it works on a phone because firebase might need a unique identifier for the phone, probably derived from IMEI.

Comment: @HonzaKalfus well thank you sir. Thats unfortunate and when I originally posted this question it was from my phone and it was difficult to type everything in and edit it. But im getting the gyst of things here at SO thanks to you. 
However that's unfortunate with the emulator. But thank you for your assistance and references.

Answer (score 0):

To check your button response do this

```
onPress={()=>alert("working...")}
```

To check your firebase response, go to the network tab of your browser's console and check your APIs by clicking your button.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33437574)